# Correctly deleting a 2D array created in a function

Tags: c++

I just want to make sure I am understanding this correctly. Although the below function returns a copy of the dynamically allocated pointer to a pointer, since the copy also is bound to the same memory, when I delete the copy the original deletes also.

Similarly the `A` and `B` matrices that are passed to the function get passed as copies but since they point to the same memory that one delete at the end will suffice.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "print.h"
int** square_matrix_multiply(int** A, int** B, int rows)
{
    int **C;
    C = new int *[rows];
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        C[i] = new int[rows];
        for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            C[i][j] = 0;
            for(int k = 0; k < rows; k++)
                C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
        }
    }
    return C;
}
int main()
{
    size_t sz = 6;
    int **A, **B;
    A = new int *[sz];
    B = new int *[sz];
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        A[i] = new int[sz];
        B[i] = new int[sz];
        for(int j = 0; j < sz; j++) {
            A[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            B[i][j] = rand() % 100;
        }
    }
    int** M = square_matrix_multiply(A, B, sz);
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        delete[] A[i];
        delete[] B[i];
        delete[] M[i];
    }
    delete[] A, delete[] B, delete[] M;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks alright at a quick glance. Just to get the terminology straight - `delete p;` doesn't "delete" the pointer. It calls the destructor of the object pointed to by `p` and then calls the deallocation function that returns the memory to the runtime. Pointers A, B and M are objects with automatic storage duration; they get destroyed when they go out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit misleading to say that "the matrices get passed as copies", but your code is correct and I think you have the right idea about why it is correct.

What gets passed to the function is actually two `int**`, so two pointers to `int*`s, and a single `int`. All of these are passed *by value*, so in a sense, *as a copy*. If you modified `A` inside the function, nothing outside the function would notice. (If you modified `A[5]` or `A[3][4]` though, that *would* propagate!)

Answer (score 0):

You guess right. The fact is that you return and pass copies of pointers to the same memory area,so when you call delete[] you are deallocating what you expect to.